# Angular2 Observable updating private variable

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

Not sure if I'm asking the question correctly, but I have a service that is used to share an array object between different components.  However, when I submit the new object to the service, something is updating all other objects in my service array.

ie 
first push
    answers = [{questionId: 1, value: 1}]
second push with {questionId: 1, value: 3}
    answers = [{questionId: 1, value: 3}, {questionId: 1, value: 3}]

Notice how the value is changed to match the value of the newly pushed answer object.

This is my service

```
export interface Answer {
  questionId: number;
  value: number;
}

  private answers: Answer[] = [];
  private _answers: BehaviorSubject<Answer[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  public answers$ = this._answers.asObservable();


  addAnswer(answer: Answer) {
    this.answers.push(answer);
    this._answers.next(this.answers);
  }
```

This is my component

```
export class LevelComponent {
  subscription: Subscription;
  answer: Answer = {questionId: 0, value: 0}; 
  a: Answer[];
  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute, public answerService: AnswerService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.subscription = this.answerService.answers$.subscribe(item => this.a = item);


  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component is destroyed
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }


  submitAnswer(e){
    console.log(e.target.id);
    this.answer.questionId = 1;
    this.answer.value = e.target.id;

    this.answerService.addAnswer(this.answer);
  }
```

Basically I'm looking to 'share' an array of answers across multiple components, but limited understanding of BehaviorSubject and subscriptions has be perplexed as to why, after adding a new item to the array in service, would it update all other objects.  On a side note, if I change the answer var to just be a number, the values in the array don't change when I submit the answer.

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kuhGT9hXE7KHKsiTCVWb?p=preview) that illustrates what I'm seeing.

Comment: What do you mean *"update all other objects"*? Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: updated with an example of how the answer object is getting updated

Comment: @jonrsharpe added a plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for those that looked at my question.

So it turns out that my service was correct and functioning as expected.  The issue was that I was passing the same reference of my answer to the addAnswer call each time, so it was updating the referenced answer which in turn updated each object in the array.

The fix was to declare a new answer each time before submitting.

```
  submitAnswer(e){
    let answer: Answer = {questionId: 1, value: e.target.id};
    this.answerService.addAnswer(answer);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your doing this:

```
this.answers.push(answer);
this._answers.next(this.answers);
```

when you only need to do this

```
this._answers.next(answer);
```

I.E By calling next with the entire array, your subscribers will receive the entire array as the next item rather than just the next item.

Comment: _answers is a BehaviorSubject<Answer[]>.  answer is only a single Answer object.  How would I push the new answer into the _answers var?